# Unknown script on Google Chrome. Causing opening a new tab with ad some times

Tags: google-chrome, script, google-chrome-extensions, malware

I recently having this problem when there is a script errors from loadingpages.info... and I cannot get rid of it even remove google chrome completely from my laptop. As I mentioned from the title, it also sometimes causes opening a new tab with ad on it. Here is the error from console:

[Error from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDG4k.png)

Are there any ways that I can get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was a Malware. It causes many problems and opening popup is one of them. I downloaded a application called Malwarebytes and scanned my mac. It removed that malware immediately. Problem solved!

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please "accept" it by clicking the checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody who used my site got the same problem in chrome on a macbook. It did not cause pop-ups, but broke links on the website itself.

At his computer the problem was solved by disabling the adblocker for that site. However I do not know exactly why, and if it will solve the exact problems that you experience. [Here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/_4VgKAPZ8SI;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/category$3Amac%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) they discuss the same problem, it seems to be some malware or extension problem.

One other thing that might be helpful: The link is loadingpaqes.info instead of loadingpages.info